# KendoUI Autocompelete - How to render kendo UI Grid onOpen event of Autocompelete control?

Tags: autocomplete, kendo-ui

I want to display Kendo UI grid when I enter any letter in autocomplete,from which I can select any one record and display information accordingly. 
For e.g. If I have Kendo UI Autocomplete to display Employee information. After typing 2-3 letter I want to display the employee information in Kendo UI Grid when Autocomplete hets open.

I have used a below template but that is displaying data in List format:

```
<span class="k-state-default" style="background-image: url(\'../content/web/Customers/#:data.Name#.jpg\')"></span>
<span class="k-state-default"><h3>#: data.emailID#</h3></span>
<span class="k-state-default"><h3>#: data.CompanyName #</h3></span>
```

Please suggest how this can be achived?

Comment: The autocomplete widget always displays a list, the template just determines how each list item is formated.

Comment: You can't use a Grid, but what you can do is to use div's in your template, and style it like a table using CSS.